# How can I make a stored procedure check it's input parameters and do a return if they are outside limits?

Tags: sql-server

I started to write a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_prepare_data]
    @SubjectId      INT
AS
BEGIN

END
```

How can I make it so the stored procedure returns with a RC of 99 if the SubjectId that's passed to the stored procedure is **not** 100,200 or 300 ?

Comment: well what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_prepare_data]  --<-- Use usp_ instead of sp_
     @SubjectId      INT
AS
BEGIN
   IF(@SubjectId = 100 OR @SubjectId = 200 OR @SubjectId = 300)
      BEGIN
        -- Your code goes here
      END 
   ELSE 
    BEGIN
        RETURN 99;
    END
END
```

Comment: Can you confirm if that should be OR or AND ? I think it might be a bit mixed up. 100, 200 or 300 are okay but anything else should return 99.